# Unknown Method Return Type with Polymorphic Template Classes in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, pimpl-idiom

I have been struggling to figure out how to implement the following classes.  Essentially what I am trying to achieve is the following:
- The main class is for a Matrix
- The data should be stored external to the Matrix object
- The Matrix_Data should be able to support both float and double types

I've been trying to work on figuring out how to implement with templates, but I cannot seem to figure it out.  This gives a general idea of my intent:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
   IMatrix_Data* m_data;
...
}

class IMatrix_Data { 
XXX Get_Data();  // <== The return type should be float or double, as appropriate
...
}
```

Can someone please give me some suggestions and some guidance?

**UPDATE:**

I have updated the class following @ruslo's suggestion.  The problem that I'm now facing is that changing the Matrix and Matrix_Data into template classes causes a chain effect to a large number of classes.  I admit that my experience with templates is very limited --- perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, or perhaps this is the right way but it just looks wrong to me.

Basically, it would seem that any class which then uses a Matrix, or the data stored in a matrix needs to be a template class.  I know that I can clean up the appearance of the code with typedef (or using statements), but I don't think that will change anything in terms of the hierarchy of classes, will it?

As an example of some classes which I have that use Matrix:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector : Matrix<T>

template <typename T>
class Input {  // <- this class is intended to be used as a base class for runtime polymorphism
    Vector<T>::DataType Get_Data();
    /* Rest of class */
};

class Parameterized_Input{ // <- this class is intended to be used as a base class for runtime polymorphism
};

template <typename T>    
class Input_Iterator {
    /* ...
           */
    std::stack<std::vector<Input<T>* >::iterator > parent_nodes; // Part of the iteration algo
}
```

I'm feeling rather confused here --- this is a little beyond anything I've done before and I'm hoping someone can help point me in the right direction here, both in terms of the implementation as well as any suggestions for improving the design.

For example, as I noted in the code above, the class Input is intended to be an abstract base class, to allow runtime polymorphism.  Derived classes will implement this interface (and possibly Parameterized_Input) to create different types of Inputs.  However, since the return type of the inputs is the same as that of the Matrix_Data -- i.e. unknown type T right now -- it seems that I will need to make every derived class into a template as well.

Unfortunately, at this time, I feel that I need the flexibility of using either a float for performance or double for precision, depending on the circumstances.  If I could rule one of these out, then it would certainly simplify everything.

The alternative -- without templates, almost appears to be simpler in the big picture (based on my possible faulty understanding):

```
class Matrix{
    IMatrix_Data* m_data;
    /*  ...   */
}

class IMatrix_Data{
    /*  ...   */
    template <typename T>
    Get_Data(int _row,int _col) { return static_cast<T>( this->ncols * _col + _row ); }
}

namespace matrix_data {
    class MD_Double : public IMatrix_Data{
        /*  ...   */
    }

    class MD_Double : public IMatrix_Data{
        /*  ...   */
    }
```

I've tried to provide enough information above, but if there's anything missing, please let me know and I'll be happy to provide additional clarification and/or information.

Thanks and regards,
Shmuel

Comment: Why does the data class have to be of one type?

Comment: My intent is that IMatrix_Data is an abstract base class and that Matrix_Data would be a concrete class which implements the interface of IMatrix_Data.  I have already written a bunch of the code without templates, and each type is a separate subclass of IMatrix_Data.  IMatrix_Data provides two (pure virtual) methods -- Get_Data_As_Float(int, int) and Get_Data_As_Double(int,int) which are implemented by the concrete classes and casts as necessary.  I don't think this is the right way to do this -- which is why I'm looking for help to clean it up.  Thanks

Comment: @ruslo, Agreed.  I am adapting existing code -- that method previously was declared virtual.  That being said, I'm still having issues with the code- I've updated the original question.

Comment: @ruslo, I am aware of that.  I didn't have the chance to update the question on Aug 23.  The updated question / code is now above.  I acknowledge that there's something potentially wrong with my design, but I'm just not sure how to allow the flexibility of choice between float and double (performance vs precision).

Comment: @ruslo, sorry, I was waiting for sufficient reputation points to be allowed to join a chat. I am now able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return value of *GetData* can be template parameter:

```
template <class T>
class MatrixImpl {
 public:
  typedef T DataType;
  DataType GetData();
};

template <class T>
class Matrix {
 public:
  typedef MatrixImpl<T> Impl;
  typedef typename Impl::DataType DataType;

  DataType GetData() {
    return data_->GetData();
  }

 private:
  Impl* data_;
};
```

Comment: Just curious -- what is the benefit of / reason for the typedef?

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I thought I tried this before and was getting strange error messages from the compiler -- I must have made a mistake somehow.  I've gotten the above to compile, but there are impacts to other parts of the code.  I've edited my original question with further details.